# Java Stream: combine elements in a map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, multiset

I have a `Map<String, List<class1> > dict` and here is what I hope to do

```
Multiset<class1> dict1 = HashMutlset.create();
SetMultimap<class1, String> dict2 = HashMultimap.create();
for (Entry<String, List<class1>> entry : dict.entrySet()) {
   dict1.addAll(entry.getValue());
   for (class1 elem : entry.getValue()) {
       dict2.put(elem, entry.getKey());
   }
}
```

I hope to put all class1 object in the lists in a Multiset and also have a reverse look up of class1 object and its key.

Is there any way to write the equivalent code using stream?

Comment: Are those Guava classes??

Comment: Consider the streamless alternative: `dict.forEach( (k,v) -> { dict1.addAll(v); v.forEach( elem -> dict2.put(elem, k) ); });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ImmutableSetMultimap<class1, String> dict2 = dict.entrySet().stream()
   .collect(ImmutableSetMultimap.flatteningToImmutableSetMultimap(
      entry -> entry.getKey(),
      entry -> entry.getValue().stream()))
   .inverse();
ImmutableMultiset<class1> dict1 = dict2.keys();
```

In general, using `Stream.forEach` to put things into a collection is an antipattern.

Comment: I think you mean `ImmutableSetMultimap<class1, String>`.

Comment: thanks sir, after thinking, and see your answer, I found yours is the best way do this things. so I deleted my answer. and thanks again for your feedback. and plus one from mine.